Git bash, cwd, and directory problems in VSCode
Somehow I broke my Git Bash integration on VSCode (windows). When I run a new terminal, the git bash prompt shows C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code instead of the correct working directory. If I cd .. it shows the correct working directory of /c/Users/myuser in the prompt and all seems okay from there with the prompt showing the correct path. Another weird thing is if I try cd ~ I get an error: bash: cd: $'C:\\Users\myuser': No such file or directory. So there's something funky going on between the expectation of home being C:\\home vs \c\home. I've tried setting the cwd in my .bashrc file, explored every option I could find in VSCode terminal settings, i.e. setting "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" or anything else but no luck. Any suggestions?

what if you disable shell integration?

Dude wt actual f. Disabling integration seems to have fixed it. Why? If you want to answer I'll mark this as resolved as well.

I'm guessing your $HOME or maybe some Windows variable like $HOMEPATH is set to something it shouldn't be.

This problem was somehow caused by shell integration. How exactly I don't know. Dumb workaround is to disable shell integration. I'm too lazy to dig further and the question post doesn't seem to give much else in "easy info" to go on. You might want to check out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_common-questions.
